# ¿Qué hace este sorted() de Python?

Tags: python, ordenamiento

Estoy pasando un código Python a C++ y me he encontrado con una ordenación que no termino de entender, ya que no manejo mucho Python.

```
def calculate_c(some_a):
    c=sorted(range(len(some_a)),key=lambda x: some_a[x])
    return c
```

some_a es una lista de enteros como puede ser esta:
[11, 15, 10, 16, 9, 17, 6, 20, 5, 21, 4, 22, 3, 23, 2, 24]

Me está devolviendo esto:
[14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]

Y no termino de comprender el funcionamiento de ese lambda/sorted, porque pensaba que dejaba los pares a la izquierda y los impares a la derecha con el 0 en medio pero veo que no. Ya que al meter una secuencia más larga de entrada, me devuelve lo siguiente:

[8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 34, 32, 30, 28, 26, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 82, 80, 78, 76, 74, 72, 70, 68, 66, 64, 62, 60, 58, 56, 54, 52, 50, 48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83]

Además de que en el primer ejemplo en some_a no hay ningún cero. Y en cambio en lo que me devuelve, si tengo un 0 ¿A qué se debe esto también?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido MarioBS a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Puedes agregar el listado inicial para crear un [mre] ??

Comment: `sorted` ordena un iterable y devuelve una lista, el parámetro `key` solo indica en base a que se hará el ordenamiento.

Comment: @Excorpion ¿Te refieres a una lista como esta?     some_x=(11, 15, 10, 16, 9, 17, 6, 20, 5, 21, 4, 22, 3, 23, 2, 24)     Llamando a esa función que puse, pasandole esta lista, debería devolver el resultado que indiqué arriba también.  Perdón por no poder poner más código, forma parte de un proyecto bastante grande y es una lista que viene de bastante más atrás creada, solo que la saqué con un printf.

Comment: @Christian Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que es en sí sorted y el key si entiendo/se lo que es, o lo que se supone que hacen. Lo que no termino de entender es eso que me dices, osea en base a que está ordenando. No entiendo el lamba x: a[x]. Tampoco que función cumple el range() que se le pasa al sorted.

Comment: `a` es una variable que en el código que muestras no está definida, esta variable puede ser un diccionario, una lista o una clase que haya implementado el método `__setitem__`. Sin saber que contiene esa variable poco podré decirte

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Perdón por las etiquetas mal puestas. Soy miembro desde hace poco más de un año, además de haber estado ojeando la página en busca de ayuda desde las sombras(sin estar registrado)desde hace bastante bastantes años. Me lo leí en su momento, pero al ser mi segunda pregunta en tanto tiempo, la verdad es que ni me acordaba bien. Gracias por refrescarme la memoria y por la edición del error.

Comment: @Christian Perdón, es una errata al escribir el código aquí. some_a y a es la misma lista de enteros. Lo corrijo.

Comment: No hay problema Mario, bienvenido.

Comment: *Además de que en el primer ejemplo en some_a no hay ningún cero. Y en cambio en lo que me devuelve, si tengo un 0* -> El problema es que no le estás pidiendo que ordene la lista que le indicas... si no una lista de 0 a N, donde N es la longitud de tu lista... Literalmente es lo que le indicas: `sorted(range(len(some_a))` Ignorando la lambda, estás pasándole al método `sorted` una lista (`range()`) de 0 a `len(some_a)`

Comment: `range(len(some_a))` genera un ietrable que empieza desde el 0 y termina en `len(some_a)-1` y es ese iterable el cual se ordenará. El parámetro `key` ordenará en base al elemento que se encuentre en la posición `x` de la lista `some_a` (`x` tomará los valores del iterable `range(len(some_a))`)

Comment: @Benito-B Tienes toda la razón del Mundo. De hecho en C++ lo tenía programado con el bucle de 0 a la longitud de "a" de hace unos meses , y hoy en cambio, llevo el día pensando que ordenaba la lista,(es un proyecto grande). Lo que me queda por entender es la lambda. Osea cuando x=0, coge a[0], es decir, el 11. ¿Qué hace con ese 11 para ordenar así?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás intentando ordenar no es la lista `some_a` sino un iterable ascendente de 0 a la longitud de `some_a`. El valor de `key` sirve para obtener el valor a comparar, en tu caso `some_a[x]` es decir, la comparación se hace entre los valores de `some_a` pero lo que se ordena es una lista ascendente. ¿Cuál es el sentido de esto? se me ocurre que es el de obtener el orden que deberían tener los elementos de `some_a` si la queremos ordenada:

```
x = [6, 2, 1]

orden = calculate_c(x)
print(orden)

[2, 1, 0]
```

La lista `orden` es la forma en que eventualmente habría que "acomodar" los elementos de `some_a`, 6 -> 2, 2 -1 y 1 -> 0. Si bien no estás ordenando la lista, obtienes un orden que fácilmente podrías aplicar:

```
print([x[i] for i in orden])
[1, 2, 6]
```

Lamentablemente `python` no tiene forma de hacer un `slice` mediante una lista, por eso hay que pasar por una comprensión de lista para hacerlo, sin embargo en el universo `pandas` si es posible y muy común "reordenar" datos mediante esta técnica.

Comment: Me expando un poco por si te es, o a alguien de interés: El proyecto trata sobre el plegamiento inverso de las proteínas de ARN. Lo que estoy haciendo es transcribir un código Python que no está escrito por mi, a un código C++ para agilizar el programa. En el programa usamos la dot-bracket notation, es decir una secuencia como esta de entrada:  ..(((((..(((...)))..)))))...    Como se puede observar, some_a, son los indices de los "pares de paréntesis" de la secuencia,es decir, la posicion 11 abre y cierra con la 15, la 10 con la 16, etc. Que si te fijas es la lista some_a.